# How is the Spotlight TableView in iOS 7 made?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit, ios7

Spotlight in iOS 7 shows a neat effect with the blurred background showing through.

I'm specifically wondering how they do the tableView sectionHeader views. They seem to be semi-transparent (like white with an alpha of 0.1) over the blurred background but if a cell is scrolled under it, they're completely opaque.

How could they've achieved this?

Comment: Thanks for the downvote without mentioning what was wrong with the question - NOT!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the headers are actually opaque, but that they're constantly updated with a blurred snapshot of the view underneath the table.  That way, although you can see through them to the background, you can't see through them to the cells.

Comment: Certainly possible. I noticed the scroll bar starts below the top section header. This lets me think they're doing some other magic here. Like masking the tableView cells but not the header views.

Comment: That's just `scrollIndicatorInsets`, you can do that on a normal table view.

Comment: Sure, it's possible to change these and it's possible I'm reading too much into it. But why are they changed like this? Looks wrong to me.

Comment: It's possible that it's not even a table view - iOS7 makes much heavier use of `UICollectionView`s than before.